# How can I persit the ouath tokens so that Im can use them in future?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am developing an application which require integration with twitter. I am using **twitter4j api** .

I have to persist the ouath tokens so that my application can interact with twitter in future.
I save the access token and access token secret . However when I am reusing them I am getting an exception token expire .

Could you please let me know the way I can reuse them and what is the expiration period of the ouath tokens ?

Answer (score 1):

from [Twitter's OAuth FAQ](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/OAuth-FAQ#Howlongdoesanaccesstokenlast):

> **How long does an access token last?**
>
> We do not currently expire access tokens. You access token will be invalid if a user explicitly rejects your application from their settings or if a Twitter admin suspends your application. If your application is suspended there will be a note on your application page saying that it has been suspended.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **cookies** to save your oauth token and oauth token secret and then make subsequent requests using by retrieving cookie data.
Like in php , i use it like this:

```
setcookie('oauth_token', $token->oauth_token);
setcookie('oauth_token_secret', $token->oauth_token_secret);
```

You can access these values by $_COOKIE['oauth_token'] and $_COOKKIE['oauth_token_secret'].but this is in php. You should see how you have to do it in JAVA.
Hope this helps you Anshul.